# Python dictionary for genetics and fastas sequences syntax

Tags: python, dictionary, fasta, genetics

Can someone explain to me this some specific line syntax ( it's not long, juste 3 lines) for this , it's for creating a definition for dictionary and writing in it from a file containang fastas sequences using nameHandle :
the lines I don't understand are the one without the #

```
def getfasta(file):                     #creating the definition

  nameHandle=open('fastas.txt,'r')      #(this is for opening the file that we're gonna use) 
  fastas={}                             #I know it means my dictionnary name
  for line in nameHandle:               #I know what it means
       if line [0]=='>':                #(it's beacause each first line in a fasta seq starts with > )
           header=line[1:]              #(Starting this line  I can't understand a thing)
           fastas[header]=''
       else:
           fastas[header]+=line[:-1]
  nameHandle.close()                    #closing the package
  return(fastas)                        #gives us the dictionary with the keys and all of content
```

Comment: The indentation in your code is a bit messed up, you should fix it to make it more easily readable.

Comment: It looks like all this is doing is extracting the names of fasta sequences, I am not entirely sure it's correct though. `line[:-1]` is a line from the file without its last character, it feels like there should be a `split` somewhere.

Comment: tried to make it the code little bit more clear now

Answer (score 0):

```
def getfasta(file):
    nameHandle = open('fastas.txt,'r')
    fastas={}
    for line in nameHandle:
        if line [0]=='>':
            header=line[1:]  # this takes the whole line except the first character and stores it into a string
            fastas[header]='' # this creates a new entry in your dictionary, with key=header and value=''
        else:
            fastas[header]+=line[:-1] # this line (except the last character, '\n') is added to the value associated to the previous header
    nameHandle.close()
    return(fastas)
```

So what happens is this: the file is read line by line. I assume the first line starts with a ">". The rest of that line (let's call it "first entry") is taken as a key for the dictionary. The following lines are then appended to the value associated. When you reach another line starting with ">", it is taken as a new key, and the following lines appended in a new value.

With the following example:

```
>entryOne
AT
CG
>entryTwo
CA
GT
```

the resulting dictionary is then:

```
{(key="entryOne", value="ATCG"), (key="entryTwo", value="CAGT")}
```

Comment: Waw thank's Darksteel and all of you,   it's so much better especially with the example !